# RSA Accumulators with auxiliary information or known trapdoor information

Tags: rsa, accumulators

In *"Universal Accumulators with Efficient Nonmembership Proofs"* by
Jiangtao Li1, Ninghui Li2, and Rui Xue3 section **"How to compute witness with the auxiliary information"** the authors write:

"The membership witness and nonmembership witness can be computed efficiently given the auxiliary information $aux_f$. Suppose there is a trusted group manager who knows $aux_f$, maintains the set $X$, and has already computed the accumulator $c = f(g, X)$, the group manager can compute (non)membership witness for any $x \in X_k$ with one short modular exponentiation.

For $x \in X$, the group manager first checks whether $x \in X$, then computes
$a = x^{−1} \bmod \phi(n)$, and finally computes $c_x = c^{a} \bmod n$. The membership witness for $x$ is $c_x$. It is easy to verify the correctness of the witness as $(c_x)^x = (c^a)^x = c^{x^{−1}·x \bmod \phi(n)} = c \bmod n$."

When I try to apply this I always get membership in the accumulator as true, even when the tested number is not in the accumulator.

Example:

$$
c = g^{x_1 x_2 \cdots x_k} \bmod n
$$

According to the authors I should calculate the witness of $p$ (a prime number) as:

$$
c_p=c^{p^{−1}mod \phi(n)} \bmod n
$$

Then check if $(c_p)^{p} = c$.  This is always true if $p^{-1}$ exists. As per the proof presented by the authors, even when $p \notin X$.

On the other hand if I store the full exponent of accumulator $c$ as $e = \prod_{i=1}^k x_i $ I can test if an element is a member of the accumulator or not by calculating:

$$
w_p = g^{e / p \mod \phi(n)} \bmod n
$$
$$
c' = (w_p)^p \mod n
$$

$$
  isMember(p) = \left \{
  \begin{aligned}
    &\text{true}, && \text{if}\ c'=c \\
    &\text{false}, && \text{otherwise}
  \end{aligned} \right.
$$

This works but I have to store the full exponent $e$ instead of just storing accumulator $c$ and using trapdoor $\phi(n)$ to calculate witnesses on the fly.

What am I doing wrong? How can I use the knowledge of the accumulator's trapdoor to calculate valid membership, or non-membership, on the fly just by knowing the accumulator's value $c$?

Answer (score 2):

For the inclusion proof you might need the trapdoor or the accumulated set. The exclusion proof can be generated without knowing the trapdoor. See this related [question and answer](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/64083/inclusion-and-exclusion-proofs-in-rsa-accumulators/76169#76169).

How can one generate inclusion proofs if knew the trapdoor, i.e. the factorization of $N=p\cdot q$?

Let's $A$ denote the accumulator's value, $x$ be an item to-be-accumulated and $N$ the modulus whose factorization is known.

Generating a valid membership proof for an item $x$ essentially means taking $x$-th root of $A$ $\mod N$. Since you know the factors of $N$ you can just compute $x$-th root $\mod p$ and then $\mod q$ and afterwards compute the $x$-th root $\mod N$ by applying the Chinese-remainder theorem for moduli $p,q$.

Note, that computing efficiently arbitrary roots mod a prime is simple. See, for instance, [here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/31311/how-hard-it-is-to-take-an-eth-root-mod-p).

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I'm trying to validate membership in the accumulator, and since secrecy is not a requirement all parameters N, p, q, and accumulator value are known. What is not known are the actual elements ($x_1, x_2, \cdots, x_n$) that built the accumulator. How can I test if a prime number $y$ has been accumulated?

Comment: By using the Chinese-remainder theorem with each of the x-th roots of A mod p and mod q, I get the same witness as calculating $w_x=A^{x^{-1}} \bmod N$ directly which is what we expect, and then when I test for membership by checking $w_x^{x} == A$ I always get this to be true even when $x$ had not been accumulated. How can I test if a given value has been accumulated or not if the person doing the verification does not know the members of the set that generated the accumulator?

Comment: You can only take $x$th roots of the accumulator value $A$ if $x$ was indeed accumulated. Otherwise you will not find such an $x$th root, namely you will not find a solution to the equation  $w_x=A^{x^{-1}}$ .

Comment: I think your misunderstanding stems from the implicit assumption of yours, that the $a\rightarrow a^x$ function in $\mathbb{F}_p$ is injective. However, this map is far from being injective.